# Efficient way to calculate average value over disjoint subranges of STL map

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, average

I'm converting an algorithm from C# to C++. A small part of the algorithm is to calculate average values for certain areas in a dictionary.

The data in the dictionary is stored in the following way:

```
Index     Value
1         10
3         28
290       78
1110      90
```

I need to calculate the average value of all values with an index smaller than a certain number and all index values larger than a certain number. In C# I do it the following way:

```
if (dictionary.Where(x => x.Key < areaWidth).Count() > 0)
{
    avgValue = (int) dictionary.Where(x => x.Key < areaWidth).Average(
        x => x.Value);
}

for (var i = 0; i < line.Length; i++)
{
    if (i == areaWidth)
    {
        avgValue = -1;
        i = line.Length - areaWidth;
        var rightBorder = i - areaWidth;

        if (dictionary.Where(x => x.Key > (rightBorder)).Count() > 0)
        {
            avgValue = (int) dictionary.Where(
                x => x.Key > (rightBorder)).Average(
                                x => x.Value);
        }
    }

    if (line[i] < avgValue * 0.8)
    {
        reallyImportantValue += (avgValue - line[i]);
    }
}
```

I know that is not very efficient and pretty crappy code, but I knew that I would have to completely rewrite this part of the algorithm in C++ anyway, so I decided to implement it quick and dirty.

Anyway I am now porting this to C++ and because it will run on a mobile platform performance is very important. With my limited C++/STL knowledge I could most likely get the job done, but the result would probably be much worse than the C# code.

So if you know a good and efficient way to accomplish this task in C++, please tell me.

---

EDIT: Thank you for all your answers. As I mentioned in my post my STL knowledge is limited, so it's really hard for me to pick a solution, especially since there are a lot of different opinions. It would be great if someone could help me with the decision, by comparing the solutions posted here. To give you a little more background information:

The function will be called approximately 500 times with 1000 values in the map. The most important aspect is stability, performance is the second most important.

Comment: Which parts are you having problems with?

Comment: @gregg I think the answer is expected to be using <algorithm> from STL.

Comment: Calculating the two average values using the map. I could iterate through all values and calculate the average, but I really doubt that this is the best solution.

Comment: Here is a link, where you can improve your C++/STL knowledge a bit http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key-value pairs in std::map are sorted by keys - it's easy to sum the values pointed by keys smaller or larger than some value even with a for loop (if you do not want to use or learn to use STL algorithms). For keys lower than some `value`:

```
std::map<int, int> map;
map[...] = ...;

int count = 0, sum = 0;
for (std::map<int, int>::const_iterator it = map.begin();
     it != map.end() && it->first < value; ++it, ++count)
{
    sum += it->second;
}
// check for count == 0
int avg = sum / count; // do note integer division, change if appropriate
```

For average of keys larger than value, use `map.rbegin()` (of type `std::map<...>::const_reverse_iterator`), `map.rend()` and `>`.

edit: STL algorithms might make the code shorter (where its used, that is). For example, to calculate the average of keys below `value`.

```
int ipsum(int p1, const std::pair<int, int>& p2) {
    return p1 + p2.second;
}

...

std::map<int, int> map;
int sum = std::accumulate(map.begin(), map.lower_bound(value), 0, ipsum);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My solution would have been very similar to the first code piece you posted. What are the pros and cons of using STL?

Comment: You are using STL, if you're using a map (std::map, that is). STL algorithms may sometimes make it more clear what the code is doing, but in this case there is little difference (the for loop version might be a bit faster)

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. So basically I have the choice between looping through the map twice, which is more efficient or using upper and lower bound, a custom function and accumulate which is slower, but will make the code shorter. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Do note that the for loop is not looping through the whole map - only through keys that are smaller (or larger) than `value` (look at the condition). But other than that, yes, that's the case here.

Comment: Apparently this answer was down-voted. I would be glad if anyone could tell me the reason why.

Comment: @eq-: Sorry for missing that. The whole iterator topic is something totally new to me and with my limited STL knowledge is quite hard to understand all the answers let alone to choose one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::accumulate` to compute the sum of the values, and then divide by the number of elements.  Here are some [examples](http://www.devx.com/cplus/10MinuteSolution/30115/1954) of how to compute the mean and other statistics using STL.

Comment: And how would that work with only picking items which have an index in a specific range?

Comment: Use `std::map::lower_bound` to get iterators to the values you care about, then pass those iterators to `std::accumulate`. For values with indices less than `x`: `std::accumulate(m.begin(),m.lower_bound(x))` where `m` is the map, and for values with indices greater than or equal to `x`: `std::accumulate(m.lower_bound(x),m.end())`.

Comment: If you want to change the less than to less than or equal, or greater than or equal to strictly greater than, use `upper_bound`. Also, I think there's a required `init` parameter I forgot to pass to `accumulate` which should be 0.

Comment: Accumulate doesn't give you the option to convert the values first. You can use a custom function but you still have a collection of std::pair to deal with. boost::transform_iterator or similar will be required first to extract the second element out of the pairs you get when iterating a map.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: one-pass map accumulator - `result2` contains the info you need:

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

typedef map<const unsigned int, unsigned int> Values;

struct averageMap
{
    averageMap() : lowerCount(0), lowerSum(0), upperSum(0) {}
    averageMap operator()(const averageMap& input, 
           const Values::value_type& current)
    {
        if (current.first > boundary)
        {
            upperSum += current.second;
        }
        else
        {
            lowerSum += current.second;
            ++lowerCount;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    static size_t boundary;
    size_t lowerCount;
    unsigned int lowerSum;
    unsigned int upperSum;
};

size_t averageMap::boundary(0);

struct averageRange
{
    averageRange() : count(0), sum(0) {}
    averageRange operator()(const averageRange& input, 
        const Values::value_type& current)
    {
        sum += current.second;
        ++count;

        return *this;
    }

    size_t count;
    unsigned int sum;
};


int main()
{
    Values values;

    values[1] = 10;
    values[3] = 28;
    values[290] = 78;
    values[1110] = 110;

    averageMap::boundary = 100;
    averageMap result = accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 
        averageMap(boundary), averageMap(boundary));

averageRange result2 = accumulate(values.lower_bound(2), values.upper_bound(300), 
    averageRange(), averageRange());

    return 0;
};
```

OLD VERSION:

This works for me.  Using `accumulate` on range retrieved from `map::upper_bound` was problematic because many STL operations require final iterators to be reachable from first in range.  There is a bit of a cheat here - assuming the `map` values are >= 0.

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef map<unsigned int, unsigned int> Values;

int main()
{
    Values values;

    values[1] = 10;
    values[3] = 28;
    values[290] = 78;
    values[1110] = 110;

    size_t boundary(100);
    Values::iterator iter = values.upper_bound(boundary);

    vector<int> lowerRange(values.size(), -1);

    transform(values.begin(), iter, lowerRange.begin(), 
        [](std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> p) 
                -> int { return p.second; });

    vector<int>::iterator invalid(find(lowerRange.begin(), 
        lowerRange.end(), -1));
    size_t lowerCount(distance(lowerRange.begin(), invalid));
    lowerRange.resize(lowerCount);

    vector<int> upperRange(values.size() - lowerCount);
    transform(iter, values.end(), upperRange.begin(), 
        [](std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> p) 
                -> int { return p.second; });

    size_t lowerAverage = accumulate(lowerRange.begin(), 
        lowerRange.end(), 0) / lowerRange.size();
    size_t upperAverage = accumulate(upperRange.begin(), 
        upperRange.end(), 0) / upperRange.size();

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: I will try your new solution and post the results.

Comment: @xsl - great, I assume this will be the fastest (and definitely least memory), but let us know.  Could probably make `boundary` static and save space without any side effects, as well.

Comment: @xsl - yes, `static` in `boundary` works here.  Updating the code.

Comment: I need the average value for a upper and lower boundary. E.g. all with a key values < 250 and all with a key > 750. I am updating your code to get these values, but you can edit your post too if you want, so that I can make sure I did everything right.

Comment: I see.  That's not a hard change.  I read this as meaning you wanted to partition the keys into those <= X and those > X.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it myself, but ran into some problems. I wanted to post them here, but now I am waiting for your update :)

Comment: Thank you, but I failed to tell you what I need again. I need two separate values: The lower average, for all values < X and the upper average for all values > X.

Comment: @xsl - this is what `averageMap` in my code does.  Check `averageMap.lowerCount`, `lowerSum` and `upperSum` after the first `accumulate` call.

Answer (score 2):

- You find your range with std::lower_bound and std::upper_bound, the difference is that lower_bound is inclusive of your value thus will give the first iterator >= your value whilst upper_bound will give you the first iterator > your value. If your value is not in the map they will return the same iterator.
- You could use accumulate but you can't just add the std::pairs together so you would need a custom functor here, or use boost::transform_iterator, or just loop once you have found your boundaries. Looping isn't as evil as some people make out (and accumulate is actually one of the most horrid algorithms).

Comment: What's so horrid about accumulate?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I understood you right, you suggest to use std::lower_bound and std::upper_bound to find the range and loop to find the average value. I did not understand the part about accumulate being horrible. Is the STL implementation horrible or is using a custom functor bad?

Comment: @xsl - `accumulate` does not work with `map` without a custom functor to perform the accumulation since `std::pair` (the `map` element) has no default `operator+`.  Since you have two ranges to accumulate, I could not find a great way of doing that single-pass.  Perhaps provide a stateful functor that accumulates in two places depending on the map key it is given ie. `pair<int,int>.first`.  I did this by splitting your map into two `vector`s and then use `accumulate` trivially.

Comment: @Steve_M accumulate uses operator+ with the construct x=x+y thus if you use a custom object it will copy the object every iteration. You provide an initial object and the result is your object in its completed state. You can put in a custom operator that takes your object by reference and cheat your template to use references, but your code may well look obfuscated.

Answer (score 1):

In the case the predicate is the comparison function of the map you're best off with `std::map<>::lower_bound()` and `std::map<>::upper_bound()`. Get the iterator pointing at the relevant bound and use that with `std::accumulate()` from `<numeric>`. Because you're working with an associative container you'll need to adapt while taking the average, so that you work with the `second` value and not with a `std::pair<>`.

If your predicate might change to something else then you can use `std::partition()`:

```
// tmp container: should be fast with std::distance()
typedef std::vector<int> seq;

seq tmp(dict.size());
seq::iterator end(std::partition(dict.begin(), dict.end(),
                                 tmp.begin(),
                                 std::bind2nd(std::tmp(), UPPER_BOUND)));

// std::vector works well with std::distance()
seq::difference_type new_count = std::distance(tmp.begin(), end);
double lower_avg = std::accumulate(tmp.begin(), end, 0.0) / new_count;
seq::difference_type new_count = std::distance(end, tmp.end());
double higher_avg = std::accumulate(tmp.begin(), end, 0.0) / new_count;
```

You'll need the `<vector>`, `<algorithm>`, `<numeric>`, `<iterator>` and `<functional>` headers here.

Comment: @Steve Townsend: Is this the solution you would recommend?

Comment: @xsl - if space is at a premium, I would investigate use of custom functor to do single-pass accumulation (you would have to count elts and sum them, so three or four state vars in all) - avoid the temp `vector`s, in other words.  Otherwise, this makes sense to me and ought not to suck perf-wise.  Have you had much luck with the other options here?

Comment: @xsl I'd advise to use `std::map<>::upper_bound()` and `std::map<>::lower_bound()` because these mean the first time you traverse the dictionary you only traverse in the order of `2*log n` elements. It also means the predicate must be a binding of the comparator of the map. If, however, you find you need to change the predicate, then partitioning the map allows for any predicate. Then the first time you traverse the map is in the order of `n` run time.

Comment: @Steve Townsend: I haven't really decided yet. The whole iterator topic is new to me, so I have a hard time understanding all the  answers. eq-'s answer is pretty straight forward and the only one I completely understand yet. You and wilhelmtell seem to know a lot about the topic and both of you probably also tested the code you submitted, which is great. So basically I am deciding between your solution, wilhelmtell's and eq-'s.

Comment: Fixed a silly bug: divide over the partition's size, not the entire container's size.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a map, the simplest solution is to take advantage of the sorted nature of the keys, as others have too. Walk through first part of list, updating accumulator and count. Then walk through second part of list, doing the same. Two loops, one after the other, and you can infer the length of the second part from the length of the first part.

Very straightforward code, that should be clear at first glance, and that creates no temporary containers. I would personally prefer this approach, for these reasons. Indeed this is pretty much exactly the code I'd write if I were doing this myself using this data structure.

```
int key = <whatever>;

std::map<int, int>::const_iterator it = map.begin(), end = map.end();

size_t num1 = 0;
long total1 = 0;

while (it != end && it->first < key) {
    total1 += it->second;
    ++num1;
    ++it;
}

size_t num2 = map.size() - num1;
long total2 = 0;

while (it != end) {
    total2 += it->second;
    ++it;
}

int avg_less = num1 > 0 ? total1 / num1 : 0;
int avg_greater_equal = num2 > 0 ? total2 / num2 : 0;
```

I don't see any point finding the end iterator for the first section using `std::lower_bound` before starting. You'll be walking through the map anyway, so you might as well check as you go. The map iteration is not free, and will potentially jump about in memory a bit -- compared to this, the extra comparison on each iteration shouldn't be noticeable.

(Of course, I'm obliged to say that you should measure this, if you want to find out for sure, because you should. This is just my educated guess about the behaviour of the optimized build.)

Comment: Two obvious changes for the debug build, if it's too slow: 1. use a `for` loop for the second loop (since you know how many items there are left) and avoid a call to `std::map<int,int>::const_iterator::operator!=`. 2. For the first loop, grab a pointer to `*it` before looking at it and avoid (in effect) one call to `std::map<int,int>::const_iterator::operator->`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is my outline for those who love using accumulate to make it slightly less painful. Let's create a class called StatsCollector. I don't care what's in it really except we will assume this is a class you will use in different places in your code that gathers collections of numbers and will give you info. Let's loosely define it. I will assume it takes doubles as its values but you can template it on value_type.

```
class StatsCollector
{
public:
   StatsCollector();

   void add(double val);

 // some stats you might want
   size_t count() const;
   double mean() const;
   double variance() const;
   double skewness() const;
   double kurtosis() const;
};
```

The purpose of the above is to calculate statistical moments from the data passed in. It is a class intended to be useful, not just a hack to fit into an algorithm to avoid using loops, and hopefully you can use it many places in your code.

Now I will write a custom functor (you could use a function) for our particular loop. I will take a pointer to one of the above. (The issue with a reference is that std::accumulate assigns to it so it will copy the object which is not what we want. It is effectively going to be a self-assign, but self-assigning our pointer is pretty much a no-op)

```
struct AddPairToStats
{
  template< typename T >
  StatsCollector * operator()( StatsCollector * stats, const T& value_type ) const
  { 
     stats->add( value_type.second );
     return stats;
  }
};
```

The above will work with any map type regardless of the key type, and with any value type that converts automatically to double, even if it is not actually double.

Now assuming we have our iterator range in our map we can use accumulate like this:

```
StatsCollector stats;
std::accumuluate( iterStart, iterEnd, &stats, AddPairToStats() );
```

And stats will be ready to analyse. Note that you can customise stats for later use in its constructor, so you can eg set flags to not calculate cubes/4th powers if you don't want it to calculate skewness and kurtosis (and even to not calculate squares if you don't care about variance).

Answer (score 0):

roughly:

- `map::upper_bound` / `lower_bound` to get the iterator for the index range
- `accumulate` to calculate the sum over the range (easy), and `count` to get the elements

---

That runs through the range twice (doesn't scale well). For optimization:

```
 struct RunningAverage
 {
     double sum;
     int count;
     RunningAverage() { sum = 0; count = 0; }
     RunningAverage & operator+=(double value) 
     { sum += value; ++count; }

     RunningAverage operator+(double value) 
     { RunningAverage result = *this; result += value; return result; }

     double Avg() { return sum / count; } 
 }
```

Which you can pass to accumulate to gather both count and sum in one pass.

---

**[edit]** As per comment, here's the rationale for the optimization:

- a O(N) algorithm with no limit given for N
- primitive operations (node traversal and addition)
- random access pattern is possible

Under these circumstances, memory access is no longer guaranteed to be cache backed, and thus cost may become significant compared to the per-element operation (or even exceed that). Iterating twice will double the cost of memory access.

The "variables" in this discussion depend only on data set and client computer config, not the algorithm.

I'd prefer this solution over a custom "accumulate", because it's simple to extend or modify for other operations, while the "accumulate" details remain isolated. It could also be used with a hypothetical `accumulate_p`method that parallelizes access (you'd need a `struct + struct` operator, too, but that is simple).

Oh, and const correctness is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: Bench-test this against a loop and see if it is "optimized". I once had a very similar issue and also wrote an accumulator. But I also stored the squares of the values so I could find the variance/sd too if I wanted. Hey, why not store the cubes and 4th powers too and we can calculate the skewness and the kurtosis while we're at it.

Comment: Nay. The first test is *is the simple implementation fast enough*. Unless you trust your compiler to fold the two loops (I don't), or expect a major hardware revolution about right now, it's just a question of N and your customers cache size.

Comment: Fast enough may be good enough but when you particularly write a comment "For optimization:" before a piece of code I want to know why you think that piece of code is there for optimization purpose. By the way, I used to implement my own algorithms and implement one called accumulate2 which used += or a custom functor/function that took an l-value and an r-value and modified the l-value. Calculating the mean requires you to store 2 numbers, the sum and the count. Your class is also not const-correct.